# Docker is maxing out CPU despite having no containers running, how can I reduce CPU overhead of docker?

Tags: macos, docker

Docker is running on macos, with no containers, yet com.docker.hyperkit is showing in activity monitor to be running 125% of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Docker -> Preferences.  Restart Docker